# HTML, CSS, z-index

Tags: html, css

I can't understand something with z-index, If you take a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4R2Pu/) you may see that there is an hidden span behind the div.

I have learned that all the elements has`z-index: 'auto';` which says that they inherit the z-index from their parents, the only element that has z-index is the html element with `z-index: 0;`, so if what I just told is true all the elements(`with position absolute, fixed, relative`) by default should have `z-index: 'auto';` which is basically `z-index: 0;`.

Now if you take a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9X76v/) I set `z-index: 0;` for the div element and to my surprise the span is no longer hidden, I'm surprised because the default `z-index` for the div should be **0** and the div should hide the span.

**So my question** is why when I set the `z-index: 0;` for the div element the span is no longer hidden, I mean the span should stay hide no?

Comment: http://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/

Comment: Your span is inside the div and therefore will stay above no matter what. Now notice that if you move your span outside, then it will be equally treated as it's new sibling (the div) and in this case will stay hidden.

Comment: I understand that, but if you take a look at both my links, what is the difference when i add z-index:0; to the div when the default is z-index:0;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this will do some help.

**The Default Value: `auto`**

The specification has this to say about the default value,`auto`:

> The stack level of the generated box in the current stacking context is the same as its parent's box.The box does not establish a new local stacking context.(CSS2.1:9.9.1)

That means: you can treat any element with `z-index:auto` as `z-index:0`.But the **difference** is `z-index:auto`won't establish a stacking context,but the latter does.

You may understand the phrase 'stacking context' as the new containing blocks established by the element whose z-index is not `auto`.

To see your problem specifically:

1)`span{z-index:-1}`   & no explicit *z-index* for *div*,actually right now the `div{z-index:auto}`

Given the rules of stacking,the *div* won't establish a new stacking context,so its child is placed in the same stacking context as the *body* element.In other words, the *span* is behind the *body* element.

2)`span{z-index:-1}` & `div{z-index:0;}`

In this situation, the *span* is part of the stacking context established by the *div* , not the initial containing block's stacking context any more.Remember this.
So, the `span` will never be stacked below the background of its stacking context ,just as your second fiddle shows.

P.S. The stacking rules are not like this until CSS2.1. ;-)